# Change Hover Color of Hyperlink in java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to change the colour of a hyperlink when hovering. Currently, when hovering it changes from green to dark blue, and I don't want it to change colour when hovering.
I think it's due to the predefined cursor.

`public JHyperlink(String text, String url, String tooltip) {`
...

```
    setForeground(Color.green.darker()); //color before hovering

    setToolTipText(tooltip);
    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            setText(String.format(html, text));

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            setText(text);

        }
```

Comment: Is it extending another class?

Comment: @Ryan I use the JHyperLink class in my JFrame class